# Understanding the el in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I don't quite understand how the el works in backbone.

I was under the assumption that el defaulted to body when it wasn't specified. I created a fiddle to illustrate my misunderstanding.

When I specify the el everything works fine. Unspecified returns nothing though.

http://jsfiddle.net/9R9zU/70/

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>Foo</p>
</div>

<div class="bar">
</div>

<script id="indexTemplate" type="text/template">
  Bar?
</script>
```

JS:

```
app = {};

app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        ""           : "index"
    },

    index: function() {
        if (!this.indexView) {
            this.indexView = new app.IndexView();
            this.indexView.render();
        } else {
            this.indexView.refresh();
        }
    }
});

app.IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({

//  el: $('.bar'),

    template : _.template( $('#indexTemplate').html() ),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    },

    refresh: function() {
        console.log('we\'ve already been here hombre.')
    }

});


var router = new app.Router();

Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Basically, your assumption that it defaults to _body_ is wrong.  It will create a detached view.

Comment: You probably should have a look at the [documenation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el), but basically if not specified the `el` is an empty div (which is not attached to the `DOM`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not specify element in the Backbone view, it will create an html node in memory, render the view into it and bind all event handlers based on that node. Then you will need to manually append it to the dom like this:

```
$('body').append(this.indexView.render().el);
```